# Strange result in Ruby with "end if"

Tags: ruby

I expect this code to execute the code block and result in the output `"x"` and `"y"`, or just to throw a syntax error:

```
if true
  puts "x"
end if
puts "y"
```

However, the interpreter ignores the `if true` block and only executes `puts "y"`. If I instead enter the following code:

```
if true
  puts "x"
end if
```

the interpreter exits with an end-of-input syntax error. Is there a reason why the first snippet is valid code but somehow executing wrong? It would seem to me that there is some error in the parser.

I've confirmed this in Ruby 2.1.2 as well as Ruby 2.1.5.

Comment: Your code is equivalent to `if puts "y"; if true; puts "x"; end; end`. `puts "y"` returns `nil`, so `if true; puts "x"; end` is not executed.

Comment: Aaaa, i get it. It executes like a one-liner.

(if true; puts "x"; end) if puts "y"

A bit tricky. Wouldn't expect it to read it that way.

Comment: Try using a [Ruby parser](https://github.com/seattlerb/ruby_parser) and see if it can explain how your code is interpreted.

Answer (score 6):

There are two things playing together here:

1. The return value of the `puts` is `nil`
2. Ruby is usually clever enough to read the next line if the current command hasn't ended yet.

That means:

```
if true
  puts "x"
end if
puts "y"
```

is the same than:

```
if true
  puts "x"
end if (puts "y")
```

Ruby evaluates `puts "y"` to nil:

```
if true
  puts "x"
end if nil
```

What leads Ruby to not evaluate the `if true` block, because `if nil` acts like `if false`.

---

Or in other words: Your example is the same as:

```
if puts("y") # evaluates to nil (aka is falsey)
  if true
    puts "x"
  end 
end
```

Comment: But shouldn't the end statement end the first if statement? Is it somehow executed as an "and" statement?

Comment: The `end` ends the first `if` statement. But the `if` in the same line than the `end` work just like the normal [modifing `if`](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#if-as-a-modifier) as you might have seen (something like this one-liner: `do_foo if bar?`).

Answer (score 3):

I think what you mean to write is

```
if true
  puts "x"
end 
puts "y"
```

That would produce the output you expect.

Comment: Why do you think that's what the OP intended?

Comment: Because he says that he expected the original code to output x and y.

Comment: He may have expected that because he thought `puts "y"` returned a truthy value. Both explanations are plausible.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is incorrect. The correct code is:

```
if true
  puts "x"
end
puts "y"
```

Your code tells Ruby to execute the `if true ... end block` if `puts "y"` returns true.
`puts` returns `nil`, which amounts to false in a condition check, leading to the block not being executed at all.

Comment: There is nothing incorrect about the syntax. It is a commonly used syntax.

Comment: You're right. I meant incorrect from the point of view of the the asker was trying to do.

Comment: You're right. I forgot myself and thought I was writing VB script ;)

Comment: @user5248817 happens with the best of us. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is effectively saying only to execute the `if true` block only if `puts "y"` returns true. Unfortunately, `puts` returns nil. To end an `if` statement in Ruby, you simple have to use `end`. Unlike in Shell Scripting or Visual Basic, there is no specific end statements for different blocks.

Change

```
if true
  puts "x"
end if
puts "y"
```

to

```
if true
  puts "x"
end
puts "y"
```

And you'll be golden.